# How do I use pry in bin/console in a Ruby project

Tags: ruby, terminal, pry

I am very new to Ruby... just started learning it a couple of weeks ago. I have a project set up in the picture below:
[Ruby Project Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD0m7.png)

The main.rb file is a module with basic arithmetic methods, for example,

```
module Main
  def sum(x, y)
    return x + y
  end

  def diff(x, y)
    return x - y
  end
...
```

as well as division and multiplication.

I wanted to create an interactive prompt, using pry, to experiment the program. From my knowledge I need to setup pry in the bin/console file in the project.

After a bit of research, I found that if I setup my bin/console file to have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "bundler/setup"
require "../lib/main.rb"

require "pry"
Pry.start()
```

Then I just need to enter `./bin/console` into my terminal to run the pry debugger.

I setup my bin/console file as above, but when I enter `./bin/console` into my terminal, it just asks me which app to open the file with.

Is there another way of doing this? What exactly have I done wrong here?

If there is any more info I can give, let me know. Thanks

Comment: Are you running a unix or unix-like system?

Comment: PSA: You don't need to explicitly `return` like this in Ruby, it's implicit. You also don't need to add empty argument lists, those can be omitted, in this case `Pry.start` is sufficient.

Comment: If this is on Windows, not sure you can use the hash-bang style declaration without using WSL and a POSIX type shell.

Comment: Run your program with `ruby   bin/console`.

Comment: _it just asks me which app to open the file with_  : Copy and paste the exact message here. Also tag your question with the operating system you are using.

Comment: _I wanted to create an interactive prompt, using pry, to experiment_ ... Is this just done for learning Ruby? Because your Ruby installation already comes with such an "interactive prompt", so you don't need to re-invent it.

Comment: You need require_relative, not require, if main.rb isn't in *LOAD_PATH*.